# Can bears smell empty beer bottles?

Tags: camping, bears, black-bears

Sometimes I camp with people who pass out drinking beer and don't bother to clean up their trash before they go to bed. Since we are in black bear country, I was wondering if empty beer bottles can attract black bears.

Comment: Recommendation: don't camp with those kinds of people, or sleep further away from them.

Comment: If you're in the middle of the woods passing out drunk, bears aren't really the largest concern.

Comment: @RussellSteen so what is a bigger concern it such a situation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This answer may depend on the type of bear, but somehow I doubt it.

> If you ever visit Yosemite National Park, go to the Happy Isles
>   Visitor Center. They have an old Jeep door on display. The Jeep had
>   once belonged by a camper who left a tube of chap stick in their car
>   as they slept.
>
> A black bear smelled the chap stick inside the closed Jeep and ripped
>   the door clean off the hinges to get to it.

Don't think about the beer bottles being "food". Think about bears being curious. Anything with a scent can attract a curious bear. Maybe your bear has never smelt an IPA before, and will need to investigate the rich scent of hops.

Take a quick look at the Yosemite National Park page on [bear safety](http://www.nps.gov/yose/planyourvisit/bears.htm).

The short version is: **put your empty beer bottles into a [bear can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear-resistant_food_storage_container) or [bear locker](http://www.nps.gov/yose/planyourvisit/lockers.htm)**.

Comment: My thought exactly. I can smell them, so a bear surely can.

Comment: Exactly! Except a bear can probably smell them from a kilometer away.

Comment: Also, lol at "bear bottles"

Comment: At first place: Why would someone (except being fool) want to carry Beer bottle on a trek/Camping thing? Carrying that much of water or some Juice would make you hang on for another day or two in worst case situations. Rather, carrying a Beer bottle and keeping it with you would probably make that Worst Case Situation for you and all who are around.

Comment: @WedaPashi I am going to guess that anyone who is getting drunk in the wild is car camping, and not backpacking. And, in that case, it doesn't matter how heavy things are.

Comment: @theJollySin: Then its okay. Here in India we hardly have places for Car Camping :( So, if I wanna go into the wild, it has to be a trek/backpacking thingy

Comment: @WedaPashi Backpacking is more fun anyway. But that's interesting to know.

Comment: @theJollySin, I often carry wine in bladders for days. Weights, but the evenings are more fun :)

Comment: @theJollySin: It always is!

Comment: @Vorac Really, you carry wine backpacking? That sounds like great fun. I considered buying a small flask and filling it with something that would also double as antiseptic. But I haven't done it yet. Sounds like fun.